# Using C# for loops to create a "V"

Tags: c#

For homework I have been asked to write a C# console program that has the user define a character and size, and the program will output an n*n/2 sized "V" where n is the width of the "V". The best I can get is either triangles or one diagonal line going left and one going right below it. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        int maxWidth = 40;
        Console.WriteLine ("Please enter your desired character");
        string userChar = Console.ReadLine ();
        Console.WriteLine ("Please enter your desired width");
        int userWidth = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine ());

        for (int i = 0; i < userWidth; i++) {///opposite diagonal lines
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                Console.Write (" ");

            }
            Console.Write (userChar);
            Console.WriteLine ();
        }

        for (int i = userWidth - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
                Console.Write (" ");

            }
            Console.Write (userChar);
            Console.WriteLine ();
        }
```

Comment: Show us what you have

Comment: Given n and the row number it is possible to determine both x1 and x2 for that row; or one could +/- the appropriate counters each row step. Simple loops or substring slicing can take care of the output. A pencil and piece of [graph] paper is a good place to start. When posting a "question" to SO, make sure to include current code for a minimal accurate reproduction case and provide an accurate description of the problematic output/result.

Comment: You need to show us what you have tried (i.e. your code) and explain why you expect it to work and where it goes wrong. (Preferably sooner rather than later to prevent further down votes.)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, as you can tell i'm pretty green with programming and i'm basically at the point where i'm stuck with this; as i don't know the ins and outs it's difficult to tell where i am going wrong or if i am even on the right track.

Comment: Thanks for posting code - now read it. You'll notice a lot of `WriteLine` calls. Please take list of paper and draw "V" with big red dots on it arranging dot in centers of cell of 9x5 grid. Count how many lines it took (should be about 5) and compare it with how many lines your code will produce... Also count dots on each line as additional hint.

Comment: When doing this should i be printing for example: charachter, 8 spaces charachter, new line, charachter, 6 spaces, charachter, newline... and so on , or is it two diagonal lines next to each other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are approaching the logic wrong by trying to calculate both sides separately.

As a hint, there are 2 spots on each row that are far away from each other at the top, and close to each other at the bottom.  Each row, they both move toward each other.  So what you want to do is figure out where they are at the top (say, 1 and 10), then each row, add one to the first and subtract one from the last, so they move closer to the middle.  at the bottom, they will meet each other.

As another hint, it is possible to complete this task using one loop.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, i suspected i was thinking about it wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
int lines = userWidth / 2;

for (var i = 1; i < lines; i++)
    Console.WriteLine(userChar.PadLeft(i) + userChar.PadLeft(2 * (lines - i)));
Console.WriteLine(userChar.PadLeft(lines));
```

I get this:

```
X                   X
 X                 X
  X               X
   X             X
    X           X
     X         X
      X       X
       X     X
        X   X
         X X
          X
```

Comment: The _PadX_ methods on `string` do not get enough visibility! Nice job.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your input, this is the code i ended up coming up with.

```
public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        int maxWidth = 40;
        Console.WriteLine ("Please enter your desired character");
        string userChar = Console.ReadLine ();
        Console.WriteLine ("Please enter your desired width");

        int userWidth = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine ());

        for (int i = 0; i < userWidth; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                Console.Write (" ");
            }
            Console.Write (userChar);

            for (int j = userWidth-1; j > i; j--) {
                Console.Write (" ");

            }
            for (int j = userWidth-1; j > 0+i ; j--) {
                Console.Write (" ");
            }

            Console.Write (userChar);
            Console.WriteLine ();
            }

        }
```